# Which git version use GitHub Gui for mac?

Tags: macos, git, github

I have installed the current latest version of git for the mac. Previously I had git 1.8.5.2 version. I have installed GitHub gui as well https://mac.github.com/.  I have setted correctly the PATH infact now when I write on the terminal `git --version` I get back the latest version 2.0.1. I have executed the .sh that come together the installation package named `setup git PATH for non-terminal programs.sh`. Now my question is: the github gui for mac os x which version of github uses? does it exist a wat to set up it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have found the solution. Inside github app there is a folder named resource and inside it there is a folder named git where there it the bin of git